# How to update options in Restsharp v107 (RestClientOptoins)

Tags: restsharp

I'm not finding any RestClient method to update its options, what I need to do is for example disable FollowRedirects for certain requests.
How do I do the following but with v107?

```
client.FollowRedirects = false;
```

Background: maybe a separate issue but current problem is that RestSharp is not following a redirect URL to Okta from a Location header of a response, it goes to the main Client URL instead. That is why I've decided to disable redirects to try following the redirect manually.

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all of the properties in `RestClientOptions` are used to configure the `HttpMessageHandler` instance wrapped by `RestClient`. As each `RestClient` instance wraps a single `HttpClient` (and its handler), those options cannot be changed. It works the same way as configuring `HttpClient`, where you *cannot* change the `AllowAutoRedirects` property of the handler once it's configured.

That's why the documentation suggests using a specifically configured `RestClient` instance per remote API. Normally, the API uses a single convention and configuration requirement.

I have seen that some authentication endpoints require redirects, but most of the time the `RestClient` instance used to get the authorization token is not the one used to access the API itself with the retrieved token. So, the solution would be to have a separate instance for that purpose. Normally, it's only used once to get the token, then you can dispose it and reuse the token.

I keep posting the authenticator example from the docs https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#authenticator

Concerning RestSharp not following redirects properly, it's not what RestSharp does as it doesn't compose or execute HTTP calls physically. It just wraps `HttpClient`.

Comment: Thanks. I created a workaround for this (instantiate new RestClient and passing the previous client's cookies + the new settings). 
To give you some context, I am using Restsharp to test an API but the login process was captured from web traffic, so there are multiple connections bewteen okta and the app server, simulating real usage. I understand chained requests with multiple domains might not be the best case scenario for restsharp. At least Postman proved to be really useful for doing this. Thanks!